# 500 Internal server error in magento and admin pages

Tags: .htaccess, magento, magento-1.7

I just changed the URL values on core_config_data (since its someone else's repo) to my own URL

but after a while the page located on my VM no longer loads.

According to firebug console:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error
```

Even admin pages cannot be accessed. Already made sure folders are rewritable by:

```
chmod 777 app/etc/

chmod -R 777 media/ var/
```

also tried moving the .htaccess from Magento home directory to other directories but same error happens.

VHOST

My vhost looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

.HTACCESS:

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

   # Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Kindly advise what should I do? Thanks

Comment: check apache `error_log`, it should be in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` in most cases

Comment: @AmitBera I just did but still same error

Comment: http://www.techjam.gr/2012/magento/solve-magento-500-internal-server-errors/

Comment: Check if FollowSymLinks is allowed in .htaccess or not. Try commenting it

Comment: @waldek_c nothing there about the issue

Comment: @DushyantJoshi I have read that already. Seems nothing works on my issue

Comment: @vishnu something should be logged, or vhost for Your Magento has own error log. And post Your main `.htaccess` here please.

Comment: @waldek_c where is vhost log located? Sorry forgot its location

Comment: @waldek_c I am using a Mac OS X

Comment: check in `opt/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: hm.. your vhost config is default apache, no new vhosts there, if i only knew how to move this conversation to chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48051/discussion-between-waldek-c-and-vishnu)

Comment: what is the permission of your index file. It should be 655
and clear "log" tables and cache.

Answer (score 10):

uncomment out `RewriteBase /magento/` and set it to `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Thank You @austin, You Save My Day  :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Try changing write permissions to your magento install folder to 755.

Comment: I install magento but i did not found install folder or directory. I look install.php file. Where is Install Folder ??

Answer (score 0):

You can open index.php file and uncomment these lines to enable developer mode of Magento for debugging.

```
#Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);
```

I got the same issue and I found out that the error was caused by .htaccess file in  Magento root folder. I tried to rename htaccess file and the error is gone.

If it doesn't work, you can try increasing phpmemory limit of your server to ~256MB by adding this line to .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value memory_limit 256M
</IfModule>
```

After that I replace that .htaccess file with original file from a fresh Magento package and everything is ok till now.

Reference source: http://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-fix-magento-500-internal-server-errors-in-magento-and-magento-2